# Having a serious issues with a trigger in SQL Server that creates two copy-tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have been having issues with this one query for more than a week. It is my first time creating a trigger, but I am supposed to create a trigger that uses INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE and I need to create two copy tables. First, I test for existence, then delete them and finally re-create them.

The purpose of this trigger will be to prevent deletions of employees from the TempEmpData table if they have a corresponding record in the TempWork table and to make sure new employees are not inadvertently given an insurance plan (ID 0 is a 90 day probation period listing). Here is my code:

```
    --Set the database context to PR
USE PR2;

--Test for the existance of a fake table named TempEmpData. If it exists, drop it.
IF OBJECT_ID('TempEmpData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempEmpData;

--Test for the existance of a fake table named TempWork. If it exists, drop it.
IF OBJECT_ID('TempWork') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempWork;

--Select everything from EmpData into the appropriate fake table
SELECT * INTO TempEmpData FROM EmpData

--Select everything from Work into the appropriate fake table
SELECT * INTO TempWork FROM Work
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TempEmpDate_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE
    ON TempEmpData
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    --(USE THIS CONDITIONAL STRUCTURE- substitute variable names where needed and remove the "--")
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted JOIN TempEmpData ON Deleted.EmpID = TempEmpData.EmpID)
             --the correct primary key)
        BEGIN;
            --Custom error message
            THROW 11, 'EmpID is in use; transaction cancelled!', 1;
            --rollback the transaction
            ROLLBACK TRAN;
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            --Update the appropriate fake table
            CREATE TRIGGER TempEmpData_INSERT_UPDATE
            ON TempEmpData
            AS 
            --Set the appropriate column to the correct value
            --Where the correct primary key is in a subquery selecting that same key from the
            --system table that handles inserts
            UPDATE TempEmpData 
            SET BenPlanID = 0;
DELETE TempEmpData
WHERE EmpID = 41;

INSERT TempEmpData
VALUES ('Bill', 'Smith', '11/14/2014', 0, 0, 1, NULL, 2);
SELECT * FROM TempEmpData
ORDER BY EmpID DESC
        END;
```

And here is the error I am getting:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TempEmpDate_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

Any suggestions, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Care to explain why the TRIGGER internall seems to create another trigger? That is the first time I ever see that construct.

Comment: @TomTom Not sure; I am learning, and so I thought I could do it that way :( Should it be ALTER instead?

Comment: It should be neither. Triggers are defined in the DML phase - not during runtime. So having a CREATE TRIGGER within a CREATE TRIGGER makes zero logical sense. And for temporary tables - those pretty much never have triggers and those have SPECIAL NAMING. Learning should involve RTFM - which you did not. Look up naming conventions for temporary tables in SQL Server. They are in the documentation.

Comment: what is the need for creating trigger inside a trigger

Comment: This is for an assignment. Sadly, a lot of them are not practical, but they want us to learn even things that are uncommon. This is based on a SQL Server 2012 textbook, but I wrote all of the code myself.

Comment: If this is a learning exercise, it seems like a terrible one. The requirements you've listed seem like they could be achieved using a foreign key and a check constraint. You should generally prefer constraints over triggers, if constraints are capable of enforcing your requirements.